# How to build nest js project with custom .env file

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I want to build a project with a custom NODE_ENV enviroment but isnt working, my current script is

```
"scripts": {
    "build:dev": "NODE_ENV=development nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "NODE_ENV=development nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/main",
  }
```

For commands npm run start:dev works well, but when I try

```
npm run build:dev
```

the output of `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` is `undefined`

Comment: Where are you calling `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)`? I'm wondering since `nest build` should just invoke `tsc` and compile your app.

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: I think you did not understand my questions :) `nest build` should just build the app and not execute code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been struggling for nearly 2 hours and couldn't find a way to create a dist folder with corresponding "*process.env.VARIABLE_NAME*" variables replaced with the .env  equivalents.

But I managed to run dist folder with env file with an npm package called **env-cmd**

First you have to install npm package

```
npm i -g env-cmd
```

Also, I assume you have process.env.VARIABLE_NAME variables and env file in your project so you can use env file.

ENV file example (lets say file name is **dev.env**):

```
MONGODB_URL=localhost
MONGODB_USERNAME=admin
MONGODB_PASSWORD=admin
```

process.env.VARIABLE_NAME usage example:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(
      `mongodb://${process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.MONGODB_URL}`,
    ),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then you should build the nestjs dist folder with build command in nestjs project directory.

```
nest build
```

Now you can go into the dist directory and run the project with this command:

```
cd dist 
env-cmd -f path/to/devenv/dev.env node .\main.js
```

I also use env-cmd for development either with this command.

```
env-cmd -f environment/dev.env nest start --watch
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You have to install two packages first:

```
npm i config @nestjs/config
```

Now, create a `.env` file on your root folder and define the environment variables on there. Such as:

```
# .env file
NODE_ENV="development"
```

Now import `ConfigModule` on the `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env',
    }),
    ...
  ]
})
```

And you don't need to modify anything in your scripts. So scripts will be as following:

```
"scripts": {
    "build:dev": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main"
  },
```

In this way, for the production, you have to only change the environment name on the `.env` file.

Comment: I did not have to install `config`, but thanks for pointing this out! A lot seems to have changed since I started working with NestJS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

> set NODE_ENV=development && nest build

Answer (score 0):

- I think you should use a docker. For example, with docker-compos.yml you can define the dotEnv file you want::

```
version: '2'
services:

  ...

  #========================  node: ===========================
  node:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/node.docker
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    env_file: YOUR_DOTENV_FILE.env
    ...
  ...
```

- An alternative solution is to save the path to dotEnv in the constant:

```
//config.ts
export const dotEnvPath = 'YOUR_DOTENV_FILE.env'
```

Then use this constant here:

```
//app.module.ts:
...
import { dotEnvPath } from './config';
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: dotEnvPath
    }),
  ...
```